# ERROR unsupported operands type(s) for *:'int' and 'Results' in for cycle

Tags: arcpy, error

I'm trying to do a for cycle to calculate standard deviation and mean for each raster in a list and after that to do a mathematical operation between them. Can someone help me to understand what is the problem?

```
ws2 = r"C:\Users\Elisa\Model_Builder\passo_5_6_7_8\output\raster_tagliati_su_flowacc"
v_name_sc_img = r"C:\Users\Elisa\Model_Builder\passo_5_6_7_8\output\outliers\{0}_out1.img"
arcpy.env.workspace = ws2
ras_names = arcpy.ListRasters()
for ras_name in ras_names:
    name, ext = os.path.splitext(ras_name)
    ras = arcpy.Raster(os.path.join(ws2, ras_name))
    mean =arcpy.GetRasterProperties_management(ras, "MEAN")
    STD=arcpy.GetRasterProperties_management(ras, "STD")
    out_ras = ras - (mean +  3 * STD )
    out_ras.save(v_name_sc_img.format(name))
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[GetRasterProperties](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/tools/data-management-toolbox/get-raster-properties.htm) is returning a [Result object](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/analyze/arcpy-classes/result.htm), not the actual value of for example mean:

> The Python result of this tool is a geoprocessing Result object. In
>   order to obtain the string value, use the Result object's getOutput
>   method.

Try using getOutput method. The output will be a string so convert it to float (or int if you want):

```
mean =float(arcpy.GetRasterProperties_management(ras, "MEAN").getOutput(0).replace(',','.'))
STD=float(arcpy.GetRasterProperties_management(ras, "STD").getOutput(0).replace(',','.'))
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply! there is another error now: INVALID LITERAL FOR FLOAT ()

Comment: @ElisaMammoliti I got the same error. It is because the digits are comma-separated and needs to be dot-separated for the float conversion. See my modified code

Comment: You're great! Now it works! thank you very very much! The last question (please be patient with me!): i need to have the full path of the previous rasters saved (path and raster name with extensions) to recall them into variables. I've tried with this:        layer = arcpy.GetParameterAsText(0)
                      desc = arcpy.Describe(layer)
                      layersource = desc.catalogPath
                      print layer

Comment: Nice could you accempt my answer with the checkbox? I dont understand your last question. The full path and name of the saved out_ras? You could list them with listrasters and a wildcard.

Comment: For example like this: `fullpathandname = [os.path.join(arcpy.env.workspace, raster) for raster in arcpy.ListRasters(wild_card='*insertwildcardhere*')]`

Comment: ok, it works but i need to create a variable for each of the elements stored within the list. Just to make you understand, i want something like this: variablename = full path with the name and extension. for example: flowaccumulation = C:\Users\Elisa\Model_Builder\passo_5_6_7_8\output\outliers\flowacc.img

Answer (score 0):

As an alternative to calling `GetRasterProperties`, you can access the [`mean` and `standardDeviation` properties](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/latest/analyze/arcpy-classes/raster-object.htm) directly.

```
ws2 = r"C:\Users\Elisa\Model_Builder\passo_5_6_7_8\output\raster_tagliati_su_flowacc"
v_name_sc_img = r"C:\Users\Elisa\Model_Builder\passo_5_6_7_8\output\outliers\{0}_out1.img"
arcpy.env.workspace = ws2 
ras_names = arcpy.ListRasters() 

for ras_name in ras_names: 
    name, ext = os.path.splitext(ras_name) 
    ras = arcpy.Raster(os.path.join(ws2, ras_name)) 
    mean = ras.mean 
    STD = ras.standardDeviation
    out_ras = ras - (mean + 3 * STD )
    out_ras.save(v_name_sc_img.format(name))
```